# Visual Studio - How to refactore javascript strings from double quotes to single quotes

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2013, refactoring, resharper

Is there an easy way to refactore all javascript strings from my solution to use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`

If i have:

```
var element = $(".classSelector");
...({
url: "<%= Url.Action("action", "controller")%>",
...
```

I would like to refactor my javascript in .js, .aspx, .ascx files to

```
var element = $('.classSelector');
...({
url: '<%= Url.Action("action", "controller")%>',
...
```

How can I do that?

Note: I also have ReSharper, but couldn't do it successfully

Comment: Any reason why Replace in Files won't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper 9.0 and above has special code style setting to address this issue. This includes highlighting and bulk quick-fix, so you're able to apply it solution-wide. 
[image: Bulk fix for quotes]

p.s.: If by some reason it doesn't work correctly for you, please [create an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RSRP&clearDraft=true&c=Assignee%20Anton.Lobov&c=Priority%20Critical&c=Type%20Bug&c=Target%20Wave%20wave02&c=Subsystem%20TypeScript&c=Fix%20versions%209.1) with a code sample.